# styled-components: How to override conditional style in a child element

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have below Base component

styled components

```
const Parent = styled.div``;

const Child = styled.div`
  ${({ selected }) => selected && `
     font-weight: bold;
  `}
`;
```

Base component

```
const Base = ({ className }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Parent className={className}>
      <Child selected={selected} />
    </Parent>
  )
}

export default Base;
```

Now I create another component that inherits `Base`, and want to change the style of the `Child` when it is selected.

Here is the concept. I want to override so that font-weight is normal when it is selected. I'm able to target the `Child` but not be able to target the selected state

```
const Wrapper = styled(Base)`
  ${Child} {
     ${({ selected }) => selected && `
       font-weight: normal;
     `}
     // this does not work
  }
`;
```

jsx

```
<Wrapper />
```

How can I target the selected state in the `Child`?